# Neighbor Polygons from List of Polygon Indices

Tags: 3d, polygon, mesh

I have a mesh in a form like [this](http://pastebin.com/8MRZqD74).
with a list of indices representing each polygon at the end. I need to generate a list of neighboring polygons for each polygon, and was wondering if anyone knows of an efficient algorithm to do this?

The simplest way that comes to mind is for each polygon, check if every other polygon has two matching indices - but this looks like it involves a few nested loops. I don't mind using this, performance isn't a huge issue here, but yeah I'm just scouting for alternatives.

There isnt any limitation on the max indices/vertices per polygon, but for simplicity's sake, lets just assume its 3 (so triangle polygons).

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i suspected as much ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ouch, XML meshes :).

I actually had a good look at this, my first answer was pretty lazy. you can write better (as posted above), and it's not that complicated, I wouldn't fork out $40 for a journal article over this. Here's a pseudo-code solution which should work for you.

**Note:** When I say table, I mean 'lookup table'.

Assume each triangle is numbered and composed of vertices, v1, v2, v3, which are uniquely numbered and can be compared using the < operator (so we can obtain unique key-combinations).

We need two look-up tables:

- An edge->(triangle list) table called edge_triangles.
- A triangle->(edges list) table called triangle_edges.

A table which tells us which triangles use a given edge, and another which tells us which edges a a given triangle is comprised of. We build these lists as follows:

```
for t = next triangle
    // Determine the ordering of vertices.
    min_vertex = min(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3);
    mid_vertex = median(p.v1, t.v2, t.v3);
    max_vertex = max(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3);

    // Register which edges this triangle uses.
    edge_triangles[min_vertex][mid_vertex].append(t);
    edge_triangles[mid_vertex][max_vertex].append(t);
    edge_triangles[min_vertex][max_vertex].append(t);

    // Set the edges that make up this triangle.
    triangle_edges[t].append({min_vertex, mid_vertex});
    triangle_edges[t].append({mid_vertex, max_vertex});
    triangle_edges[t].append({min_vertex, max_vertex});
for next t
```

Using these lists, we can take the edges in a given triangle, use these as the key into the edge table, and see which polygons share that edge. Thus, the adjacent triangles. So for a triangle t we could do the following:

```
adjacent = edge_faces[face_edges[t][0]];
```

which is pseudo-code for 'adjacent is equal to the list of triangles that share the 0th edge of the triangle t', where 0th is just the first.

We use min, median and max to make sure that that we don't have different entries for identical edges: for example {v1, v2} and {v2, v1}, where v1 and v2 are two vertices. We could actually ignore this and add a 'compact' step, where we concatenate lists which correspond to different entries in our edge list but actually correspond to the same edge.

One other possible problem with this is if you have two edges which are coincident but don't share common vertices. In this case, you could reduce either edge to a parametric equation, compare them for coincidence, and form a lookup table which tells you, for a given edge, which edges are coincident, so map:

- edge->(edges list) table called edge_coincident_edges.

We use yet another look-up table because we can't concatenate the edge->faces table. Cosider if edges e1 and e2 are adjacent, e2 and e3 are, but e1 and e3 aren't. if we concatenated the e1, e2 and e3 entries in the edge->face list, you'd end up with some wildly incorrect data. This a probably bit more than you want to do, but it's the problem I had to solve this morning :).

In the case where each edge can only correspond to at most 2 triangles, we can do away with the 'list' in the traditional sense that we can append, and use a fixed-size array of size 2. This will reduce your memory overhead and improve memory efficiency. so our edge table would be more akin to:

- An edge->(first triangle, second triangle) table called edge_triangles.

Anyway, the basic algorithm is extensible to any number of polygons with any number of edges (not necessarily the same between all polygons), and is O(N) time with respect to the number of triangles (or polygons in the general case). Space complexity is O(E + N) Where E is edges and N is the number of polygons. The look-up time should be close to O(1), assuming you have good hashing algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for this Liam! It will definitely help alot of people, including me. Its kind of mind boggling right now, but Ill re-read it a few times until I fully understand the processes involved.

Comment: your set of edges should be {min_vertex, mid_vertex}, {mid_vertex, max_vertex}, {max_vertex, min_vertex}. It is important to keep the order given in the triangle when you build the list of edges.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you are solely interested in triangulized meshes (or any simplex in *n*-D), there actually are faster solutions! The time complexity of the suggestion you make is O(*k*^2), where *k* is the number of triangles. This means that for a large number of triangles the time needed to compute the neighbors increases quadratic, which is computationally prohibitive in most situations.

I would suggest you read the article of Ueng and Sikorski ("A note on a linear time algorithm for constructing adjacency graphs of 3D FEA data", *The Visual Computer* **12**: pp. 445-450, 1996). The authors explain a linear time algorithm O(*k*) for finding the neighbors in a tetrahedral mesh, from which you can easily deduce a similar algorithm for triangulized meshes. Perhaps you will be able to expand this to general polygons as well!

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks pretty intense! When I reach the stage where I need to up the performance, i'll definitely try it out.

Comment: You're welcome! I've been working on a similar problem, and there is indeed very little information regarding this particular issue to be found (at least with the keywords I have used)... Anyway, happy to help!

Comment: @HopsC I've come across the same problem, see my post below for an O(N) solution which can handle both vertex adjacency and true geometric adjacency (with additional steps).

Comment: @Aralox I've added a less-crappy answer, let me know what you think - I think it should satisfy your need for speed :).

Comment: @Liam Good job :) It is similar to the work of Ueng and Sikorski. However, I have a question. Where you mention "...we can take the edges in a given triangle, use this as the key into the edge list, and see which polygons share that edge", do you mean that for each triangle edge you seach a lookup table to find the adjacent trias? Because this would imply that if you perform such a routine for multiple polygons you still have a O(N^2) complexity (as you traverse a list of N rows N times to find neighbors). ...Need for speed: Nice! :)

Comment: @HopsC Not quite, list should have been table, this should have been these. You would take each successive edge in a triangle (which consists of two vertex ID's) and look up the key in the table. This should be amortized O(1) for a hash table, O(log N) for an ordered list. There is no second traversal, once per edge, 3 lookups per triangle (or zero, if you hold a reference after the first search) would give you every adjacent triangle, in the simple case.

Answer (score 0):

Without precomputed data it is not possible to do it faster than looping through all faces.

For precomputed data it is enough for each vertex to hold a list of faces where it is used. Finding neighbors is done with intersecting face lists of 2 vertices.