# Find exterior edge of triangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

A 3D surface is made from triangles with common vertices. I want to find the exterior edge, which might be concave.

All interior triangles have common vertices with neighbours. Ie no vertex is partway along an edge.

There are no holes. The surface is not closed.

From other posts here it seems the best way is to build a list of edges, then discard all edges that are duplicated. What should remain are the exterior lines.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846501/neighbor-polygons-from-list-of-polygon-indices/8846969#8846969) post mentions sorting the vertices in Min, Mid, Max order:

```
// Determine the ordering of vertices.
min_vertex = min(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3);
mid_vertex = median(p.v1, t.v2, t.v3);
max_vertex = max(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3);
```

Presumably, median(p.v1 should be t.v1, and v1 format is x-value, y-value, z-value of each vertex.

I cannot figure out how to do this after many hours, and would appreciate any plain-language help or algorithm.

Speed of calculation is not a huge factor. 5-10000 triangles in Excel/vba

Comment: What  edges are exterior for icosahedron surface (just example)?

Comment: @MBo The surface in question is not closed.  Imagine an icosahedron made of triangular facets, with at least one facet deleted.  There are 16 triangles with 3 common edges, and 3 triangles with 2 common edges.  My primary question, which was not clear, is how to describe vertices as Min, Max, and Mid.