# How can one compare vertices in a triangle

Tags: 3d, polygon, mesh

In this post [Neighbor Polygons from List of Polygon Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846501/neighbor-polygons-from-list-of-polygon-indices), in the accepted answer, for a given triangle consisting of three `Vector3` points, they store its three edges as `{min_vertex, mid_vertex}`, `{mid_vertex, max_vertex}`, `{min_vertex, max_vertex}`, where `min_vertex`, `mid_vertex` and `max_vertex` are the  "sorted" triangle points (vertices).

But how does one compare vertices in a triangle structure? Do we compare the lengths (square root of sums squares of x, y and z value) of each vertex?

`Vector3` here is a struct consisting of three floats x, y and z.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the coordinates at all. A triangle is a defined as sorted set of three vertices (which could be 2D, or 3D, or ND).

min_vertex is just the vertex given in first position of the triangle, and max_vertex is the last one.

Also, your set of edges should be {min_vertex, mid_vertex}, {mid_vertex, max_vertex}, **{max_vertex, min_vertex}**. It is important to keep the order given in the triangle when you build the list of edges.